# Grails errors switching to second DB with TNS string as Datasource

Tags: grails, datasource, tns

I use a TNS string as url of my Grails Datasource, with two oracle DBs (ora01, ora02).  It connects to the db service ok during normal operation.  Here is the config:

```
dbString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = 
                  (ADDRESS_LIST = 
                        (LOAD_BALANCE = ON) 
                        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ora01.foo)(PORT = 1521)) 
                        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ora02.bar)(PORT = 1521))
                  ) 
                  (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = orastage)))"

dataSource 
{
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    username = foo
    password = bar
    url = dbString
    logSql = false
}
```

When the DBAs switch off ora01 and restart ora02 as the active one, the Grails app doens't realise and throws JDBC errors:

```
2013-04-26 11:41:35,428 ERROR JDBCTransaction - JDBC commit failed
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1142)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1099)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:288)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOCOMMIT(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:75)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:565)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3851)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3857)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:334)
```

Does my config look ok?  I'm assuming Grails can take a TNS string as datasource URL as it connects ok before we try failing a db - is this correct?  It's like the app is still trying to connect to the dead db and not trying the other node.   Do I need to get Grails to do anything specific to switch to the now-working node?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `(FAILOVER=ON)` in the description.

```
dbString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = 
                  (ADDRESS_LIST = 
                        (LOAD_BALANCE = ON) 
                        (FAILOVER=ON)
                        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ora01.foo)(PORT = 1521)) 
                        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ora02.bar)(PORT = 1521))
                  ) 
                  (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = orastage)))"
```

Comment: Apologies for delay in replying.  I've tried FAILOVER=ON too (but I think the driver assumes ON by default anyway) but same result, doesn't seem to realise the DB has dropped and won't switch to other address.  Same exception as above.  I've to leave this for the moment to work on other things but will post results of solution/investigation when I get back to it.  Thanks.